# Reduce upload time to aws s3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am uploading some files to an s3 bucket using Java. The size of each file is very less (~ 2KB). However the number of files is very large (~ 1 Mil). Due to this the upload takes a lot of time, around 2-3 hours. Is there anyway to reduce the upload time? I use the `putObject` method for each file.

Comment: Do it in parallel?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes, obviously. I meant that is there any aws method I can use for this.

Comment: Take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/aws-s3-multipart-upload). There's a section about parallelism at the end.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca multipart upload is to upload a large object concurrently

Comment: s3 has multipart upload, in it i believe there are some options such as partSize and parallel. The defaults are usually 1MB and the browser default. you may need to play around with these settings based on the browsers network connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no methods in AWS directly to run your workloads in parallel. Instead take a look at Java multithreading and process your upload function concurrently: [Multithreading in java with examples](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/03/multithreading-in-java/)